# How to install Parse.com 'Cloud Code' on Windows?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Parse.com have released their 'Cloud Code' JavaScript API, but there are no instructions for getting started on Windows.

How do you go about getting up and running in a Windows environment?

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide

Comment: I have the answer for this, but low rep prevents me from posting it for 7 hours!

Comment: The install shell script in the installation guide just downloads a (compiled) python file which you can probably just download by hand and use in a python interpreter on windows. This also means that the whole process (starting with the installer script) should work in cygwin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what I did to get Parse.com Cloud Code running on Windows 8.

- Install Python 2.7 (parse don't tell
  you this)
- Install [Git for windows](http://msysgit.github.com/) (Msysgit)
- Run 'Git Bash' as Admin, which will
  give you a bash style command line.
- Make sure Python is working in the Git Bash... `python`
- From here you can follow the [Parse
  instructions](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#started-installing), but remove 'sudo from
  the command they give you:

  `curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | /bin/bash`

From here it worked for me.

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 1):

We released an official version of the command line tools for Windows last week. Check it out at http://blog.parse.com/2012/10/25/parse-command-line-tools-available-for-windows/

Comment: I tried that and it keeps crashing on Windows 7 64 bit I don't know why.

Comment: Does it report any error message to you? The [exe version](https://parse.com/downloads/windows/console/setup.exe) of the installer will also install any dependencies (i.e. .NET 4.5) you may be missing.

Comment: Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: parseconsole.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 50897b7e
  Problem Signature 04: System
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.17929
  Problem Signature 06: 4ffa5c88
  Problem Signature 07: 3fd5
  Problem Signature 08: 3b8
  Problem Signature 09: System.ComponentModel.Win32
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3

Comment: That is the error outputted from Windows, other than that there aren't any other reported errors.