# /bin/env: python: No such file or directory (Windows through Git Bash trying to install new Parse Cloud Code)

Tags: python, windows, msysgit, git-bash

Trying to install python from the [link here](http://www.python.org/download/) does not seem to give access to the `python` command in Msysgit... following [the instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436475/how-to-install-parse-com-cloud-code-on-windows), does not actually say how to get `python` to work as needed.

Current error when running `parse new project_name` is:

> /bin/env: python: No such file or directory

I believe it's likely because it installed it at `C:\Python`... anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You're running `parse new project_name` in git bash? What's the output of `env` under PATH?

Comment: If it's not your correct python dir, could you try running `set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Python\ `?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This error means that Git Bash does not know where your python.exe is. It searches your normal windows search path, the `PATH` environment variable. You're probably failing the 4th step on the instructions already "Make sure Python is working in the Git Bash":

```
$ python --version
sh.exe: python: command not found
```

To fix that, append `C:\Python` (or wherever you installed python) to your `PATH` environment variable in windows [(instructions here)](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm). You need to restart the bash after this for the change to take effect. This will allow you to run python from the windows command prompt as well.

```
C:\> python --version
Python 2.7.2
```

---

If you don't want to alter your windows `PATH` variable or make python only available to git bash, you could create a `.bashrc` file in your `%USERPROFILE%` directory and set the variable there:

```
C:\>notepad %USERPROFILE%\.bashrc
```

and add

> export PATH=/c/Python:$PATH

to the file. That script is executed every time you start the git bash and prepends `C:\Python` to git bash's `PATH` variable, leaving the system-wide PATH variable untouched.

Now that you know what has to be done, you can use this shortcut on the bash instead (appends the export command to your .bashrc)

```
$ echo export PATH=/c/Python:\$PATH >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: The latter solution worked, tried the first but must have done it wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I had to add to my PATH env variable: c:\python32

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. If you're using Python 2.7 like the instructions say to, you could try instead of that doing "C:/Python27/python.exe" insted of "python".

Comment: I am, only problem is when I do `parse new project_name` where can I specify that different application path?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add the location of the python.exe in the PATH environment variable. Follow the steps: Go to My Computer->Right click->Properties->Advanced System Settings->Click Environmental Variables. Now click PATH and then click EDIT. In the variable value field, go to the end and append ';' (without quotes) and then add the absolute path of the .exe file which you want to run via Git-Bash.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if this could be your issue, but its always worth a check.
check your python path is set correctly?
computer->properties->advanced system settings-> environment variables->system variables->PYTHONPATH, value = C:\PYTHON20;C:\PYTHON20\DLLS;C:\PYTHON20\LIB;C:\PY THON20\LIB\LIB-TK