# /bin/env: python2: No such file or directory (Windows through Git Bash trying to install GNU Radio)

Tags: python, windows, git-bash, gnuradio

I am trying to install GNU radio on win64 using Git Bash following the instruction [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091522/bin-env-python-no-such-file-or-directory-windows-through-git-bash-trying-to)

but I got this error when running `./pybombs config` :

```
    /bin/env: python2: No such file or directory
```

I already followed the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091522/bin-env-python-no-such-file-or-directory-windows-through-git-bash-trying-to)

but it didn't work. There is a difference in the error that I'm getting since it's looking for `python2` rather that `python`   ..Also, when I check using `which python` and `python --version` everything seems to be OK. 
Do you know any solution to this problem ?

Update : There is a difference in the error that I'm getting since it's looking for `python2` rather that `python`  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091522/bin-env-python-no-such-file-or-directory-windows-through-git-bash-trying-to)

Comment: Your title shows a different error than what you have in your actual question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [/bin/env: python: No such file or directory (Windows through Git Bash trying to install new Parse Cloud Code)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091522/bin-env-python-no-such-file-or-directory-windows-through-git-bash-trying-to)