# GitHub XED Building Instructions

Tags: python, windows, git-bash, xed

I'm trying to follow the abbreviated GITHUB building instructions as shown [here](https://github.com/intelxed/xed) and here

```
git clone https://github.com/intelxed/xed.git xed
git clone https://github.com/intelxed/mbuild.git mbuild
cd xed
./mfile.py
```

The first three commands works fine. But when running the last one I get the following error:

```
$ ./mfile.py
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3’: No such file or directory
```

I've installed python version 3.11 to the following directory c:\python and have tried the following SO solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091522/bin-env-python-no-such-file-or-directory-windows-through-git-bash-trying-to).

[EDIT] I have discovered that when I navigate to the directory where mfile.py is located in Git Bash and run the command./mfile.py that its not python is that is executing (interpreting this file) its git-bash. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first your `%PATH%` (in a regular CMD shell window): it must include `C:\python`, and you should be able to type `python3 -V` to test.

Then, in that same CMD, you can type `bash` and try again your command: the  [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) should trigger `python3.exe`.

If not, copy `C:\Python\python.exe` to `C:\Python\python3.exe` and the shebang will work.

Comment: VonC@ thank you. Sorry for the late reply. FirstLY the PATH environment variable does include c:\python and from the CMD prompt the following does not works $ python3 -V Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases. But the following does work:    $ python -V
Python 3.11.2

Comment: VonC@ the following command also works from GIT-Bash: $ python.exe mfile.py. Why doesn't ./mfile.py not work ?

Comment: @JkT OK: for testing, can you copy `python.exe` as `python3.exe` in `C:\Python`, and try again you bash session?

Comment: VonC@ I followed your instructions and it worked!